# Can I use loggin keys of third part apps, in my telegram bot?

Tags: python, java, security, bots, telegram

I want to use this library in my project to code my bot in Java.

https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots

This is recommended in telegram bot API  docs. But it's said "Please, DO NOT PUSH ANY TOKEN OR API KEY, I will never accept a pull request with that content". Does it mean, I can't manage personal data of loggin info of my users? Because I want bot to interact with some credentials for websites. And I need to find another way to display my script. If  Telegram Bot can use this info in it's logic.

Thanks in advance!

I only want to know if I can use a bot to run my script. And handle this info.

Comment: The maintainer does not want people pushing user info into their project - make a copy or fork the repo for your personal project.

Comment: the maintainer ask to not include in git some secret, that all. You can probably use them through environnement variables.